# Controlling a servo with hardware PWM using wiringPi

Tags: hardware, c, pwm, wiringpi

I tried controlling the servo with softPwm using the wiringPi Library but this made the servo stutter.
Therefore I want to use the hardware PWM pin on the Raspberry Pi (GPIO18) with the wiringPi library.
But I don't understand how to set the frequency to 50 Hz and change the duty cycle to have a pulse width ranging from 0.8 ms to 2.5 ms.

I found the following relationship on the internet (i dont know if it is correct):

```
pwmFrequency in Hz = 19.2e6 Hz / pwmClock / pwmRange.
```

i know the **clock divisor max value is something around 4000** and the Raspberry Pi PWM clock has a base frequency of 19.2 MHz. so this gives me ~4,8KHz.

i already got these settings which should give me ~50Hz using the following relationship:

```
//put PWM in mark-space mode, which will give you 
//the traditional (and easily predictable) PWM    
pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
//setting ping GPIO 18 as a pwm output
pinMode(18,PWM_OUTPUT);
//Set clock divisor to 4000
pwmSetClock(4000);
pwmSetRange (10) ;
```

I dont got a oscilloscope to test the output signal to check what setting changes what. this makes it hard to find it out myself.

Long story short:
Can anyone tell me how I can achieve a duty cycle with a pulse width of 0,8ms to 2,1ms for controlling a servo using the hardware PWM on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Try connecting a led and setting the clock divisor to 50x higher. Next set the duty cycle to 50% and check if the led blinks once a second.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer (hence, it's a comment) but you might want to try using ServoBlaster - it's working wonderfully for me.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "Long story short: Can anyone tell me how I can achieve a duty cycle with a pulse width of 0,8ms to 2,1ms for controlling a servo using the hardware PWM on the Raspberry Pi.".

Recent Pis (the ones with the 40 pin expansion header) have two hardware PWM channels available.

Channel 0 is available on GPIO 12 and 18.  Channel 1 is available on GPIO 13 and 19.

So you can have hardware PWM on GPIO 12/13/18/19.  However 12 and 18 will have the same settings as will 13 and 19.

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) has C, Python, and command line methods to choose the settings.

From the command line

> pigs hp GPIO 50 dutycycle

will start PWM at 50 Hz on GPIO (12, 13, 18, or 19) with dutycycle.  dutycycle is 0 for 0% (off) or 1000000 for 100% (fully on).

0,8 ms is 0,8 / 20 % or a dutycycle of 40000.
2,1 ms is 2,1 / 20 % or a dutycycle 0f 105000

So for GPIO 18 with 0,8 ms pulses use

> pigs hp 18 50 40000

By the way pigpio and servoblaster will let you generate servo PWM on any of the GPIO.

The pigpio method to generate a servo pulse of 0,8 ms on GPIO 23 is

> pigs servo 23 800 # 800 denotes the desired pulse width in microseconds

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same process. I finally got it by using a division of 1920 for the clock and a range of 200. This is more close to 50Hz, the requirement for servo SG90. Having range 200 it give you a resolution of 0.1ms. So for a 0.8 width it will be *pwmWrite(PWM_NUMBER, 8)*. The PWM_NUMBER will depends on where you connected it and what type of setup function you use from wiringPi. If *wiringPiSetupGpio()* you can keep the 18 (GPIO24) if *wiringPiSetup()* then it work with 1.